# com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to complete transfer: Connection pool shut down

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have simply configured Spring AWS Cloud:

```
<aws-context:context-credentials>
    <aws-context:simple-credentials access-key="${s3.key}" secret-key="${s3.secret}"/>
</aws-context:context-credentials>

<aws-context:context-resource-loader/>
```

I'm trying to upload file onto bucket

```
ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
meta.setContentType(contentType);
meta.setContentLength(bytes.length);

try (ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
    TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(this.amazonS3);
    Upload upload = transferManager.upload(BUCKET, fileName, bis, meta);
    UploadResult result = upload.waitForUploadResult(); // here is an exception!
}
```

Same exception appears if I use another method:

```
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(BUCKET, fileName, bis, meta);
request.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
amazonS3.putObject(request);
```

It causes exception Stacktrace :

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to complete transfer: Connection pool shut down
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.AbstractTransfer.unwrapExecutionException(AbstractTransfer.java:277)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.AbstractTransfer.rethrowExecutionException(AbstractTransfer.java:261)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadImpl.waitForUploadResult(UploadImpl.java:66)
...

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.lease(AbstractConnPool.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.lease(AbstractConnPool.java:217)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingClientConnectionManager.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:72)
    at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy11.requestConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:416)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:749)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:505)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:317)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3595)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1382)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(UploadCallable.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:123)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:139)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
```

It looks like `PoolingClientConnectionManager` has arrived here from `apache httpclient 4.5.2` which I also use in my project

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But it is just an assumption. The problem may be some where else. Any ideas?

Comment: I followed answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469437/spring-cloud-aws-with-transfermanager-unable-to-complete-transfer-connection) Solution - tx.shutdownNow(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found workaround, but it requires completely change method of `Amazon S3` configuration:

```
<bean id="basicAwsCredentials" class="com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials">
    <constructor-arg name="accessKey" value="${s3.key}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="secretKey" value="${s3.secret}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="amazonS3Client" class="com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client">
    <constructor-arg name="awsCredentials" ref="basicAwsCredentials"/>
</bean>
```

In such configuration everything works like a charm.

---

So, it looks like Spring's `aws-context` works wrongly, or I use it wrongly. But in previous configuration autowired `AmazonS3` instance wasn't `null`, so I don't know the reason why it doesn't work properly.